# RESTEasy client API

Tags: spring, resteasy

Spring has a very good client API for REST Client: RestTemplate. Effectively it is like a Facade which encapsulates some bootstrap code (in the same way as JmsTemplate and JdbcTemplate). Is there an equivalent in JBoss's RestEasy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be one - [RESTEasy client framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html)

Answer (score 0):

Further on in the doc: 
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework

```
ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(url);
ClientResponse<String> response = clientRequest.get(String.class);
String resteasystr = null;
if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
   resteasystr = response.getEntity();
   System.out.println("**** " + resteasystr);
}
```

thanks.